# GetMatchingProductForId() only returns a result if there's an active offer

Tags: amazon-mws

As per subject, GetMatchingProductForId() returns results, eg. when querying by EAN and trying to get an ASIN back, only if active offers exist for that ASIN.

Essentially, if noone (else) is selling this product while we query, we can't get an ASIN for our EANs.

This behaviour is consistent with MWS's documentation.

The same behaviour applies to ListMatchingProducts() it does /not/ return results for non-buyable products.

As an example, using GetMatchingProductForId() for EAN 8301029074792 on the UK marketplace returns nothing whereas if you perform the same search using Seller Central you see that a listing does exist for that product.

Since Amazon wants developers not to create products if they already exist in their database, I wonder how we're supposed to query by EAN in order to get an ASIN.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution for this kind of problem. Both the affiliate's itemLookup and mws GetMatchingProductForId don't return asins if there's no current seller.

One solution I came up is to create a bot/crawler to programmatically run through all your (no matched) EAN/UPC list to the seller central's add-a-product page, search the EAN/UPC in the search bar and get the data result.

It returns the ASIN for the specific UPC/EAN query even though there's no current seller for the item.